# Yum packages - where to find / check for AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, yum, amazon-ami

I am currently trying to deploy a django application to my AWS elastic beanstalk. I am using the eb command line tool for this.

Unfortunately it fails in the YUM and requirements.txt for pip.

However, I believe there is a better process than trying to Google what the package name is. 
Unfortunately I cannot find any official Amazon image yum repository.

How do you find out the package names?

My 100 lastlog:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-activity.log
-------------------------------------
        File "/tmp/pip-build-9wom8lzp/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
          from setup_posix import get_config
        File "/tmp/pip-build-9wom8lzp/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
          from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
      ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      Traceback (most recent call last):

        File "<string>", line 20, in <module>

        File "/tmp/pip-build-9wom8lzp/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>

          from setup_posix import get_config

        File "/tmp/pip-build-9wom8lzp/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>

          from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

      ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

      ----------------------------------------
      Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-9wom8lzp/MySQL-python
  2015-04-13 05:17:35,549 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --use-mirrors -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 34, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 29, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install --use-mirrors -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --use-mirrors -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: Using base prefix '/usr'
  New python executable in /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3.4
  Not overwriting existing python script /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python (you must use /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3.4)
  Installing setuptools, pip...done.
  Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.4
  You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 6.1.1 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  DEPRECATION: --use-mirrors has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Explicit uses of --index-url and/or --extra-index-url is suggested.
  Collecting Django==1.7.4 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
    Using cached Django-1.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting MySQL-python==1.2.5 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
    Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-9wom8lzp/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
          from setup_posix import get_config
        File "/tmp/pip-build-9wom8lzp/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
          from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
      ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      Traceback (most recent call last):

        File "<string>", line 20, in <module>

        File "/tmp/pip-build-9wom8lzp/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>

          from setup_posix import get_config

        File "/tmp/pip-build-9wom8lzp/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>

          from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

      ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

      ----------------------------------------
      Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-9wom8lzp/MySQL-python
  2015-04-13 05:17:35,549 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --use-mirrors -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 34, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 29, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install --use-mirrors -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --use-mirrors -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2015-04-13T05:17:35.554Z] INFO  [551]   - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03deploy.py] : Activity failed.
[2015-04-13T05:17:35.554Z] INFO  [551]   - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Activity failed.
[2015-04-13T05:17:35.554Z] INFO  [551]   - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0] : Activity failed.
[2015-04-13T05:17:35.555Z] INFO  [551]   - [CMD-AppDeploy] : Completed activity. Result:
  Command CMD-AppDeploy failed.
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.483Z] INFO  [686]   - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.700Z] INFO  [686]   - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.700Z] INFO  [686]   - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.700Z] INFO  [686]   - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.700Z] INFO  [686]   - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.876Z] INFO  [686]   - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity.
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.876Z] INFO  [686]   - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
  Command CMD-TailLogs stage 0 completed.
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.876Z] INFO  [686]   - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.876Z] INFO  [686]   - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.876Z] INFO  [686]   - [CMD-TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
  Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded.
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.311Z] INFO  [715]   - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.530Z] INFO  [715]   - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.530Z] INFO  [715]   - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.531Z] INFO  [715]   - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.531Z] INFO  [715]   - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...



-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
-------------------------------------
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  DEPRECATION: --use-mirrors has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Explicit uses of --index-url and/or --extra-index-url is suggested.
  Collecting Django==1.7.4 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
    Using cached Django-1.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting MySQL-python==1.2.5 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
    Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-9wom8lzp/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
          from setup_posix import get_config
        File "/tmp/pip-build-9wom8lzp/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
          from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
      ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      Traceback (most recent call last):

        File "<string>", line 20, in <module>

        File "/tmp/pip-build-9wom8lzp/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>

          from setup_posix import get_config

        File "/tmp/pip-build-9wom8lzp/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>

          from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

      ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

      ----------------------------------------
      Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-9wom8lzp/MySQL-python
  2015-04-13 05:17:35,549 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --use-mirrors -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 34, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 29, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install --use-mirrors -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --use-mirrors -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2015-04-13T05:17:35.555Z] ERROR [551]   : Command CMD-AppDeploy failed!
[2015-04-13T05:17:35.555Z] INFO  [551]   : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"(TRUNCATED).../lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py\", line 540, in check_call\n    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)\nCalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --use-mirrors -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1. \nHook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.","severity":"ERROR","timestamp":1428902255},{"msg":"Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --use-mirrors -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1","severity":"SYSTEM","timestamp":1428902255}]}],"truncated":"true"}
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.481Z] DEBUG [686]   : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.481Z] INFO  [686]   : Received command CMD-TailLogs: #<ElasticBeanstalk::CommandRequest:0x007f351dac2ae8>
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.481Z] DEBUG [686]   : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.482Z] DEBUG [686]   : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-59932798)..
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.482Z] INFO  [686]   : Command is applicable to this instance (i-59932798)..
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.482Z] DEBUG [686]   : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.482Z] INFO  [686]   : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.482Z] INFO  [686]   : Command processor should execute command.
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.482Z] DEBUG [686]   : Storing current stage..
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.482Z] DEBUG [686]   : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.483Z] INFO  [686]   : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.483Z] DEBUG [686]   : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.483Z] DEBUG [686]   : Refreshing metadata..
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.697Z] DEBUG [686]   : Refreshed environment metadata.
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.697Z] DEBUG [686]   : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.698Z] DEBUG [686]   : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.698Z] INFO  [686]   : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish"].
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.699Z] INFO  [686]   : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.700Z] DEBUG [686]   : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.700Z] INFO  [686]   : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.700Z] DEBUG [686]   : Setting environment variables..
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.700Z] INFO  [686]   : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.700Z] DEBUG [686]   : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.700Z] INFO  [686]   : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.700Z] DEBUG [686]   : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.700Z] INFO  [686]   : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.876Z] INFO  [686]   : Running AddonsAfter for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.876Z] INFO  [686]   : Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded!
[2015-04-13T05:18:19.877Z] INFO  [686]   : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[{"msg":"[Instance: i-59932798] Successfully finished tailing 7 log(s)","severity":"INFO","timestamp":1428902299876}]}]}
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.309Z] DEBUG [715]   : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.309Z] INFO  [715]   : Received command CMD-TailLogs: #<ElasticBeanstalk::CommandRequest:0x007f2b689eaad0>
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.309Z] DEBUG [715]   : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.310Z] DEBUG [715]   : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-59932798)..
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.310Z] INFO  [715]   : Command is applicable to this instance (i-59932798)..
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.310Z] DEBUG [715]   : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.310Z] INFO  [715]   : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.310Z] INFO  [715]   : Command processor should execute command.
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.310Z] DEBUG [715]   : Storing current stage..
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.311Z] DEBUG [715]   : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.311Z] INFO  [715]   : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.311Z] DEBUG [715]   : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.311Z] DEBUG [715]   : Refreshing metadata..
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.528Z] DEBUG [715]   : Refreshed environment metadata.
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.528Z] DEBUG [715]   : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.529Z] DEBUG [715]   : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.529Z] INFO  [715]   : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish"].
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.530Z] INFO  [715]   : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.530Z] DEBUG [715]   : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.530Z] INFO  [715]   : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.530Z] DEBUG [715]   : Setting environment variables..
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.530Z] INFO  [715]   : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.530Z] DEBUG [715]   : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.530Z] INFO  [715]   : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.531Z] DEBUG [715]   : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
[2015-04-13T05:20:07.531Z] INFO  [715]   : Running 1 of 1 actions:
```

TailLogs...

What I actually have to install (I come from a debian system):

```
libmysqlclient-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev
```

and my requriements.txt:

```
Django==1.7.4
MySQL-python==1.2.5
Pillow==2.7.0
PyPDF2==1.24
argparse==1.2.1
cffi==0.8.6
cryptography==0.7.2
diff-match-patch==20121119
django-braces==1.4.0
django-cors-headers==1.0.0
django-debug-toolbar==1.2.2
django-import-export==0.2.6
django-ipware==0.1.1
django-summernote==0.6.3
django-xsendfile==1.0
enum34==1.0.4
geoip2==2.1.0
ipaddr==2.1.11
maxminddb==1.1.1
paypalrestsdk==1.8.0
pyOpenSSL==0.14
pyasn1==0.1.7
pycparser==2.10
pycrypto==2.6.1
reportlab==3.1.44
requests==2.5.1
shortuuid==0.4.2
six==1.9.0
sqlparse==0.1.14
suds==0.4
tablib==0.10.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

ConfigParser has been renamed to [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) in python3 (which you're using above).

You can try `configparser2` [module](https://github.com/shubhamchaudhary/configparser2) to use same configparser in python2.
Add it in your [requirements](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/configparser2) or do `pip install configparser2` and then use something as simple as:

```
try:
    import configparser
except ImportError as e:
    import configparser2 as configparser
```